# Versionamento de Código BitBucket

Tags: git, versionamento, bitbucket

Boa tarde galera, trabalho em uma empresa de desenvolvimento de sites e estamos com a ideia/necessidade de hospedar todos os sites no github/bitbucket para deixarmos de utilizar o velho e bom FTP como principal "versionador" de código.

A bronca é que, todos os sites tem um servidor especifico, afinal de conta são clientes separados e a minha ideia é a seguinte.

Exemplo de utilização real:

1. Criar projeto no github/bitbucket
2. Importar arquivos para o projeto
3. Todos os pushs para o repositório devem cair também no servidor especifico do cliente.

Ou seja, queria que além de o projeto estar "hospedado" no github/bitbucket gostaria que os pushs fossem enviados automaticamente para o servidor do cliente.

Gente, antes que me julguem eu não estou pedindo código ou que vocês façam por mim só estou querendo saber se isso é possível e caso não me deem alternativas, links, um norte para que eu comece a estudar essa "funcionalidade". obrigado a todos!!

Comment: Acho que o ideal seria usar o GIT para versionamento e o Jenkins para automatizar o "build" dos sites.

Comment: Nilson, não conheco o Jenkins mas vou procurar sobre ele agora mesmo, quer dizer que ele faz algo desse tipo?

Comment: Sim, vc consegue, entre outras coisas, configurá-lo para checar alterações no GIT e enviar arquivos para o FTP.

Comment: Perfeito, vou estudar essa ferramenta!

Comment: Você quer enviar como administrador diretamente, sem uma "triagem", vejo muita gente fazendo coisa parecida e é nisso que começam os problemas e tornam o GIT quase inútil,  disse "quase" porque ainda sim você terá um controle minimo, mas se a equipe for grande e todos tiverem privilégio de fazer o merge no `master` então vai ter grandes chances de acidentes. Do meu humilde ponto de vista, deve haver um Master e depois `pull-request` com forks, sendo assim só o Master aprova o merge ou não, parece burocrático, mas creio ser relativo e vai do costume de uso da maneira provavelmente ideial.

Comment: O importante é entender o que é GIT e como usar com uma equipe grande. Mas é tudo opinião minha, veja que tem gente que discorda deliberadamente de mim, ou seja eu posso estar talvez enganado, não sou especialista e nem nada. Note que se for um projeto simples ou pequeno, talvez não seja realmente tanta burocracia.

Comment: Então Guilherme, deixa eu te explicar +/- como funciona aqui, temos 2 dev apenas que são 1 front e 1 backend e todos os nossos projetos são em servidores remotos utilizando FTP para publicar os arquivos mas com isso além de não termos controle sobre errors e coisas do tipo também é muito incômodo trabalhar diretamente com filezila, por isso estavamos querendo começar a utilizar o git para essas questões.

Comment: @Desenvolvimentodesites como eu disse, se é algo simples, realmente talvez seja muita burocracia, então todos serem "masters", o dev front e o back não haverá problema algum, esse controle não depende do software e sim de configurar no teu servidor GIT, depende muito do servidor que esta usando se será o Github ou Bitbucket, só pra constar o Bitbucket tem opção privada.

Comment: Exato Guilherme, estou optando pelo bitbucket exatamente pelo fato dele ser privado.

Comment: Então aprenda o básico de Git e no próprio site cadastre ambos devs como  "master", então ambos podem enviar as atualizações e ainda terá um controle para fazer rollback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Todos os pushs para o repositório devem cair também no servidor especifico do cliente.

Pesquise por continuous deployment (ou CD) e as ferramentas que podem auxiliar como o Jenkins, CodeShip, etc.

Se você já está familiarizado com o Git, experimente os [Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Também tem a opção de [pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) do GitBucket que é recente e um pouco mais complexa de configurar.

Comment: Obrigado Dipi, eu não havia visto ainda a opção Pipelinis do Bitbucket, fui em busca e consegui executar exatamente o que eu queria.

Answer (score 1):

Existem diversas ferramentas que você pode utilizar para este seu cenário, a que eu indico é o [Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS)](https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/team-services/).

Bom, oque é o VSTS? É uma plataforma de DevOps, onde você encontra diversas funcionalidades para "melhorar" sua vida em um cenário exatamente como esse.

Algumas das funções são:

- Controle de Versões, utilizando repositórios GIT ou TFVC;
- Planejamento Ágil, Gerenciando todas suas tarefas,seu Kanban, etc
- Builds automatizadas, para garantir a qualidade e integridade de sua aplicação
- Deployment Automatizado

Como você pode notar, você pode fazer muita coisa ali.. Para atender essa sua idéia, você pode ao realizar um push para a master, disparar um processo de build que irá realizar as validações como se não tem código quebrado, testes automatizados, qualidade,etc, e após isso pode iniciar seu processo de deploy e implantar sua aplicação no servidor de seus clientes.

O VSTS é uma ferramenta gratuita para times com até 5 desenvolvedores, você também tem gratuitamente 240 minutos por mês de build/deployment para suas aplicações.

Embora o nome da ferramenta seja Visual Studio Team Services, ela não trabalha apenas com .Net, você pode muito bem utilizar seu projeto em Java por exemplo, já que os agentes de build e deploy também rodam em máquinas linux, ou seja o VSTS é multi plataforma.

Se quiser saber mais sobre o VSTS, eu tenho alguns vídeos no meu canal

- [Primeiros Passos com VSTS](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMFPOLE2cW1wynLrJqkAyfvCxRKsOqX-w)
- [Java com VSTS](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMFPOLE2cW1zn-_b7MahptaHJ04PaKYNt)
- [Deploy de Banco de Dados com VSTS](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMFPOLE2cW1ww5_g6HzzVwNVbCvOJeU4p)